# How to place a single infinite plane in ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

How can I place a plane with infinite length using arcore.
I want to do exactly like this github discussion [URL](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/186). 
The I found solution for unity ARCore sdk : [link](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/TrackableHitFlags.cs#L53).

So how can I achieve that using java?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up two different elements.
in ARCore you have a plane which is mapped surface on which you can put your objects. Examples you've provided are referring to GameObject. You can put as big "plane" as wide/long area you've mapped using your camera. Because first, you need to map the surface. Of course you can put as big GameObject as you want but this is

Comment: Thanks for reply, but can I change the size of detected plane?

Comment: @HardikMahant no. The detection is made by arcore framework. Of course, you can draw everything that you want on the screen (for example you can put as big GameObject as you want) but it has nothing to do with the detected plane. The detected plane is part of the world that arcore mapped and understood and on those surfaces you can put your objects using anchors

Comment: @Fixus can you please give me the reference that support your answer that ARCore framework limit the plane detection or user cannot expand the size of detected Plane

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat a detected plane as infinite, you can use [Plane.isInExtent](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Plane#isPoseInExtents(com.google.ar.core.Pose)) to check whether a Pose is in this plane.

If you want to use this in combination with some Sceneform UX functionality, you could create an own version of [TranslationController](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TranslationController) that uses isInExtent instead of isInPolygon (the default way).

Comment: Thanks for reply steven, but I think this will only work if I'm dragging 3D object on the plane (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: For the translation controller it's true. But using Plane.isInExtent() works of course for every operation.